# AWS EventBridge, SQS and Lambda with Serverless Framework

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, serverless, serverless-framework, aws-event-bridge

I'm fairly new to the Serverless Framework but I was able to achieve a lot of the bits and pieces of our aspired infrastructure using the framework and the `serverless-lift` plugin.

[image: serverless intrastructure]

The `serverless-lift` plugin allows me to easily create worker queues with workers and DLQs for each of them. That's exactly what we need as it allows us to redrive the failed jobs. See this great article https://medium.com/serverless-transformation/serverless-queues-and-workers-designing-lift-d870afdba867 (under "A production-ready approach")

The Serverless Framework can create Lambda functions triggered by the EventBridge - that's also amazing.

However, as seen in the diagram we'd like the EventBridge to put the events - according to rules - into the respective queues. That bit seems to be missing or I haven't found it yet.

**My question now:**

Can I, and if so how can I, have the EventBridge be the central piece in our infrastructure, serving events to the worker queues?

From what I read I'd be able to define resources via CloudFormation notation (see below). Since Serverless is so much simpler and can easily be handled by our developers, I'd like to avoid using CF if possible.

Another approach could be to have intermediate Lambda functions putting the event into the queues but it's adding unnecessary complexity.

Thanks in advance!

For those interested, here's the CF code:

```
# serverless-list constructs
constructs:
  my_queue:
    type: queue
    worker:
      name: my-dev-my_queue_worker
      handler: src/functions/hello-dlq/handler.main

# CloudFormation
resources:
  Resources:
    EventBridge:
      Type: AWS::Events::EventBus
      Properties:
        Name: my-dev-event-bus
    EventBridgeSQSRule:
      Type: AWS::Events::Rule
      DependsOn:
        - EventBridge
      Properties:
        Name: my-dev-event-bus-rule1
        Description: Test Event Bus
        EventBusName: my-dev-event-bus
        EventPattern:
          source:
            - test.v1
        State: ENABLED
        Targets:
          - Arn:
              Fn::GetAtt:
                - ${construct:my_queue.queueArn}
                - Arn
            Id: SQSQueueTestV1
    EventBridgeSQSSendPolicy:
      Type: AWS::SQS::QueuePolicy
      Properties:
        PolicyDocument:
          Version: '2012-10-17'
          Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Principal:
                Service: events.amazonaws.com
              Action: sqs:SendMessage
              Resource: arn:aws:sqs:${aws:region}:${aws:accountId}:*
        Queues:
          - ${construct:my_queue.queueUrl}
```

Comment: Serverless wont be able to cover all use cases as its actually platform agnostic. Your specific case is best served by using CF

Comment: Thanks @GWed. Other platforms would probably allow the same concept and as EventBridge as such is supported as Lamdba trigger I had hoped there was a way to do it with Serverless.

Comment: @robbash were you able to accomplish this without using CF?

Comment: @GeorgeDurzi no, unfortunately not. Our SLS config was in TypeScript tho and we generically generated the code for those functions where needed. (We've moved on to SST.dev since which makes it a lot easier, to achieve what you want.)